# Why axios and fetch is not working for https url call in android?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

when ever i call api using axios and fetch in android i am getting error like this in my logcate.

_response: 'java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.'

i have tried all the solutions but nothing is worked for me.

i am getting error when i run open ssl check command in terminal for my domain

depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = www.geniusedusoft.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = www.geniusedusoft.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = www.geniusedusoft.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1

Answer (score 1):

First, try to check the date-time of the device. If the device time is wrong, you will receive a certificate error. If it is not the case, you should check the https certificate, [this can happen for several reasons, including](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#CommonProblems):

1. The CA that issued the server certificate was unknown
2. The server certificate wasn't signed by a CA, but was self-signed
3. The server configuration is missing an intermediate CA

Comment: is this Error is from my side or server side?

Comment: If the certificate has an issue, it is server-side.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to add `usesCleartextTraffic` to `AndroidManifest.xml`.
It solved my problem.